# Parallel downloading images from url inside Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, parallel-processing

I am working on a script that takes a list of names and for each, it downloads 3 images from URLs. To take each name from an array I use Promise.all, there is no problem yet. But I want to download 3 images for a player in parallel, to make it faster because I need to do it the fastest way. So I see that if I download only 1 image, it takes ~2min to go through all names. But if I add 2 images more to download for a player I get >8min to go through all names. Bot it is illogical, no? If I do 3 parallel downloading it has to have the same time as 1 downloading (+/-) What I do or think wrong? Here is my code, for parallel downloading I use Pqueue library, for image downloading image-downloader npm lib

```
const {default: PQueue} = require('p-queue');
const queue = new PQueue({concurrency: 10});

const download = require('image-downloader');
const fs = require('fs');

const playersListDataUpdate = async function(playersList, serverId, currentTimeStamp){
    let values = [];
    let placeholders = '';
    await Promise.all(playersList.map(async (name) => {
        values.push(name, currentTimeStamp, serverId);
        placeholders += ' (?, ?, ?),';

        //Update skins of user
        if (!fs.existsSync('../uploads/players/'+name)) {
            fs.mkdirSync('../uploads/players/'+name);
        }

        await queue.addAll([
            async () => {
                //Head
                try {
                    await download.image({
                        url: 'https://minotar.net/avatar/'+name,
                        dest: '../uploads/players/' + name + '/face_' + name + '.png'
                    });
                    console.log('Saved skinhead of '+name);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('Failed to save head of '+name);
                }
            },
            async () => {
                //Preview
                try {
                    await download.image({
                        url: 'https://minotar.net/armor/body/'+name,
                        dest: '../uploads/players/' + name + '/skin_preview_' + name + '.png'
                    });
                    console.log('Saved skinpreview of '+name);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('Failed to save skin preview of '+name);
                }
            },
            async () => {
                //Skin
                try {
                    await download.image({
                        url: 'https://minotar.net/skin/'+name,
                        dest: '../uploads/players/' + name + '/skin_download_' + name + '.png'
                    });
                    console.log('Saved skindownload of '+name);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('Failed to save skin of '+name);
                }
            },
        ]);
    }));
    return {
        'values': values,
        'placeholders': placeholders.slice(0, -1)
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you running it in a browser? Many browsers limit the amout of concurrent requests to one domain. I would add another console.log to the very start of each async function and check if each one prints right away.

Comment: @MatthiasHauert, I run it in shell

Comment: Mh, then it should be faster, if the server is not throttling or something. Have you tried to add more logs? I suggest adding them just before each `await download`. And if you could supply some working examples for the `playersListDataUpdate` function, i will try to run it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not returning a promise from your `map` so your `promise.all` doesn't have any promises to run in parallel.

change your line where you are doing `addAll` to return the promise instead of resolving. Like this

```
return queue.addAll([
....
]);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I don't really need to go through names in parallel, what I need is to download images inside each in parallel. But it doesn't matter if I use a queue or just will put three downloads synch each after each, I will get the same 8 minutes, and that is weird for me. If I remove downloads at all it would be 30sec, if I will add one download it would be 2mins, if I add 2 more downloads (whatever synch or queue) it would be 8 mins. I expect that it would be around 2 mins with 3 downloads in a parallel queue.